# Why is $\frac{13}{10} = e^{\ln\frac{10}{13}*x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Why is:
$$\frac{13}{10}^{-x} = e^{ln\frac{10}{13}*x}$ $

I thought that the $\ln$ and the $e$ canceled out making it equivalent to saying:
$$e^{\ln\frac{10}{13}*x} = \frac{10x}{13}$$

Is this not correct?

Comment: @Eevee Trainer:  You have assumed where the parentheses should go, which OP did not specify.  The last line is not correct and I can't tell if that is the intent.  I would roll back and let OP clarify.

Comment: The positioning of the parentheses is both immediately clear from the nature of the problem and the formatting in the original code, `\frac{13}{10}^{-x}`, at least in my opinion. The last line I would argue is a simple mistake on the OP's behalf owing to some misconceptions about how $e$ and the natural logarithm interact. But as you wish.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer:  I am more persnickety than many about parentheses.  We see lots of posts where they are omitted, sometimes it is clear what is meant and sometimes not.  If I see $1/2x$ is that $\frac 1{2x}$ or $\frac 12x$?  I then err on the side of forcing OP to answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$
e^{x\ln(10/13)}
=e^{\ln((10/13)^{x})}
=\left(\frac{10}{13}\right)^{x}
=\left(\frac{13}{10}\right)^{-x}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Your question is missing the $-x$ term in the power.

Further, $\ln$ never canceled out with $e$, it is by the property: $e^{\ln x}=x$

Now in your case, $\frac{13}{10}^{-x}=\left(\left(\frac{13}{10}\right)^{-1}\right)^x=\left(\frac{10}{13}\right)^x=e^{x\ln (\frac{10}{13})}$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the fractions in each case are flipped, and that taking the reciprocal of a fraction is the same as raising it to the power of $-1$. Then we have

$$e^{\ln(10/13) \cdot x} = \left(e^{\ln(10/13)} \right)^x= \left( \frac{10}{13} \right)^x =  \left(  \left( \frac{13}{10} \right)^{-1} \right)^x = \left( \frac{13}{10} \right)^{-x}$$

Answer (score 0):

You need some parentheses to show the order of operations.  You title does not match the first line of the question, but the question looks to match what is going on here.  When you write $\frac {13}{10}^{-x}$ do you mean $\left(\frac {13}{10}\right)^{-x}$ or $\frac {(13^{-x})}{10}$?  Similarly, when you write $ e^{ln\frac{10}{13}*x}$ do you mean $ e^{(\ln\frac{10}{13})*x}$ or $ e^{\ln(\frac{10}{13}*x)}$?

For the question as edited (is that what you meant?) you can do
$$\left( \frac{13}{10} \right)^{-x} =\left(e^{\ln \frac {13}{10}}\right)^{-x} \\
=\left(e^{-x\ln \frac {13}{10}}\right)\\
=e^{x\ln(10/13)}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that:

$e^{\ln (\frac{10}{13}x)}=\frac {10}{13}x $.

But

$e^{(\ln \frac {10}{13})x}=(e^{\ln \frac {10}{13}})^x=(\frac {10}{13})^x=(\frac {13}{10})^{-x} $.

You aren't missing any concept.  You are just not reading the question as the person who wrote it intended.  Which, arguably, could be the authors fault.